# Aggregate data with minus field value

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a big table with this data format:

```
_id, ip, crateTs, txid, topic
```

I can have a single txid with multiple IPs and different createTs.
I want to have a result like this:

```
txid (unique), ip, min(createTs)
```

where the ip is the one with the minum creatTs.

I use this function:

```
db.bigdata_collection.aggregate( [ { $match: { txid: { $ne: null } } }, { $group: { _id: {txid: "$txid"}, createTs: { $min: "$createTs" }, "ip": {"$push": "$$ROOT.ip"}} }, { $sort: { createTs: -1 }},{$out: "min_dates"} ], {allowDiskUse: true})
```

and it seems to work well, except that the ip filled is an array with all ips sorted by createTs:

```
{ "_id" : { "txid" : "c79ac6597b3dc3d48c1dcb45409e1944456813763feed31bc088ae21341bc2ea" }, "createTs" : NumberLong("1555330238021"), "ip" : [ "3.8.9.247:8333", "176.9.139.80:8333", "31.130.250.38:8333", "78.45.46.181:8333", "120.76.24.5:8333", "103.255.45.49:8333", "172.104.33.80:8333", "165.227.117.68:8333", "178.163.48.144:8333", "92.62.231.253:8333", "193.70.32.13:8333", "47.254.152.192:8333", "188.250.66.207:8333", "74.67.240.204:8333", "90.240.79.110:8333", "217.232.243.242:8333", "178.163.48.144:8333" ] }
```

How can I get a single ip entry matching the minimum createTs?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712993/mongo-db-find-all-records-with-highest-value-depending-on-a-key-field/54713728#54713728

Comment: fixed used $project and $slice