# MongoDB group to get min value of a field & it's respective data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of products like this:

```
[
  {
    productName: "productB",
    productImage: "http://some.url/product_B.jpg",
    productCategoryId: 34,
    productPrice: 10
  },
  {
    productName: "productA",
    productImage: "http://some.url/product_A.jpg",
    productCategoryId: 34,
    productPrice: 50
  }
]
```

What I have so far is the following :

```
db.local.aggregate(
   [
      {
         "$match":{
            "productCategoryId":34
         }
      },
      {
         "$facet":{
            "byCategory":[
               {
                  "$group":{
                     "_id":"productCategory",
                     "minprice":{
                        "$min":"$productPrice"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

I need to aggregate/group by a single field (category) and get the minimum price per category, but I would also want to return the product name and image (other 2 fields) for the document with the minimum price for each category. Anyone can point to some direction or examples? The groupBy and min are covered, only the part of extracting extra information.
Updated the schema and the aggregation I have already, @PulkitAgg1010
What I would like it to get the productImage and productPrice for the record with the minPrice for each category.

Comment: Where do you've the field `productCategory`? Is that `"_id":"productCategoryId"` or are you creating it new from group ?

Comment: Possible dupe of [Mongo DB find all records with highest value depending on a key field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712993/mongo-db-find-all-records-with-highest-value-depending-on-a-key-field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$productCategory",
    "doc": {
      "$min": {
        "minprice": "$productPrice",
        "productName": "$productName",
        "productCategory": "$productCategory"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$doc" }}
])
```

[**`$min`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) always takes the minimum value of the first expression which is passed inside the object. Here it is value.

Comment: That seems like a great feature, especially when the alternative is probably some form of [$reduce](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/).
Any idea why it's undocumented?
I really hope this is not unintended and removed in later versions.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to use `$facet` for this, try below queries :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "productCategoryId": 34 } },
    /** group on `productCategoryId` & get `minprice` on all docs & also push all docs into data array, 
     * Also you'll only have `"productCategoryId": 34` so need not to say ``"_id": "$productCategoryId"  in group */
    {
      "$group": { "_id": "$productCategoryId", "minprice": { "$min": "$productPrice" }, data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } }
    },
    /** unwind data array */
    { $unwind: "$data" },
    /** match the docs which have `data.productPrice` equivalent to `minprice` - 
     * If there are multiple matches you can use `$limit` after match stage to limit result */
    {
      $match: {  $expr: { $eq: [ "$data.productPrice", "$minprice" ] } }
    },
    /** make `data` as new root of doc */
    { $replaceRoot: {  newRoot: "$data" } }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W5nCJuL45pB)

If you think you'll have too many docs to do `$unwind`, then try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "productCategoryId": 34 } },
    /** group on `productCategoryId` & get `minprice` on all docs & also push all docs into data array */
    {
      "$group": { "_id": "$productCategoryId", "minprice": { "$min": "$productPrice" }, data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } }
    },
    /** re-create `data` array with matched docs */
    { $project: { data: { $filter: { input: "$data", cond: { $eq: [  "$$this.productPrice",  "$minprice" ] } } } } },
    /** unwind data array */
    { $unwind: "$data" },
    /** make `data` as new root of doc */
    { $replaceRoot: {  newRoot: "$data" } }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oQrw59EmPKG)